Light switch voltage tester confusion
I have been puzzled by a light switch issue in my house-  1920s home with non grounded electrical throughout most of it.  A few weeks ago I had an AFCI breaker start tripping seemingly without reason, we  hadn't changed any appliances, put nails/screws through the walls. The breaker was tripping immediately after I flipped it.  I had an electrician friend come out and he verified the breaker was wired correctly, we eventually located a light switch that seemed to be causing the trip whenever it was flipped on.
Light switch is a 2 gang, one switch controls a light fixture in our mudroom and an exterior light, the other switch I believe controls another set of exterior fixtures that we haven't used since we moved in. These are the only switches for the fixtures. I put my voltage tester on the box and everything was reading hot- neutrals, hots, the box itself, including the switch that we don't use and keep off.   The two switches had a jumper wire in between them that looked a little frayed , I removed the wire and now the mudroom/exterior fixtures appear to be working normally again but my voltage tester is still reading everything is hot- is there something else to be looking for?  I've read that without a ground it might set the tester off like that. Appreciate any insight!

If a non contact tester, that is usual.  They are only to tell you not to place fingers near hot wires.  An AFCI breaker senses electric arcs/sparks which can happen with loose connections, switches when turning on/off, pulling a plug out of receptacle when being used/hot.  The breaker should have lights saying why it tripped, an arc or overload.
